# Unable to start Pivotal tc Server in Spring tool Suite

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, server

I am trying to run a basic MVC project in STS. When I click Start on the Pivotal Server I get the following error:

[image]

[image: This where I click Start]

What could possibly be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this kind of problem many times. I then used to

Right click on server and ***clean*** + Again Right click on server and ***clean tc server work directory***

This always worked for me. May be it may help you as well.